# Android OSM zoom level 19 and above

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, zooming, osmdroid

I'm new to Android Development. I have an application that shows a MapView and I've set a bounding box to restrict the user to only viewing the tiles in a specific area. The issue I have is that I need to zoom in, past level 18. Which I've also been able to do so by setting the max zoom level. However, there aren't any tiles available from the default tile provider for zoom 19 and above I really only require up to 20, 21 max too.

Is there a way for me to create my own tiles? Have custom tiles? Generate my own map? Or if there's a tile provider that allows me to zoom into the map past level 18 and still be able to see the map tiles?

I need a higher zoom level because I'm overlaying custom markers and if it's not zoomed in enough, the markers overlap. If I scale the marker size down, it's not visible enough...

EDIT: Some other specific details I missed on my initial post,

1. I'm using OpenStreetMap because I need the feature it provides where I can edit the roads and tag them accordingly for future routing uses.
2. Also, the tiles that Google Maps provides for my selected geographical area is outdated due to recent construction and renovation. That makes the map unreliable for routing the application user.
3. The application's purpose is to route the user. Hence the requirement to zoom in closer to see many markers, individually. (There are a number and row of markers placed very close together, intentionally.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you using Osmdroid, there are some know issues with > 19 zoom levels to be aware of. Basically it's a precision loss issue. There's a potential solution, however the project owner doesn't want to merge it.

> Is there a way for me to create my own tiles?

Yes. There's a few tools, such as Mobac, and MapBox as well as the Ersi based products. I'm sure there are others.

> Have custom tiles?

Yes, you can load any tiles source you want, online or offline that supports or can be translated to OSM's slippy map format, commonly referred to as XYZ.

> Generate my own map? Or if there's a tile provider that allows me to zoom into the map past level 18 and still be able to see the map tiles?

Bing, and probably other sources, have tiles that are at 19+ for certain geographic regions, but not all. Keep in mind that storage requirements (if using offline maps) increase exponentially with zoom level.

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending the time answering my question! I'll look into these! :)