# Loading map tiles after zoom level 19

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am working with osmdroid and trying to display map tiles past the zoom level of 19. I have set the mapview max zoom to be 20, and told the tile source to use a max level of 20 as well. I can "zoom" to the level 20 (it just appears more pixelated as it doesn't seem that Mapnik actually provide them at that level) which at the minute is OK, but then when I pan across to outside of the current tile no new tiles get loaded

```
mMapView.setMaxZoomLevel(20);
mMapView.getTileProvider().setTileSource(new XYTileSource("Mapnik", null,
            0, 20, 256, ".png", new String[] {
            "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/",
            "http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/",
            "http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/" }));
```

Is there a way to get it to load these tiles whilst still zoomed in? I have read some answers that say there is an issue with zooming past 19 in osmdroid ([Android OSM zoom level 19 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554214/android-osm-zoom-level-19-and-above)), so I am not sure if this is something to do with that...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android OSM zoom level 19 and above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554214/android-osm-zoom-level-19-and-above)

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, no. As you zoom in past the available tiles, the animator for zooming in stretches the previous tile to fill the screen during animation. Once the new tile is loaded, it's redrawn with the correct tile.

It's possible to attempt to retrieve tile current zoom -1, then stretch and crop it to fit the screen, but that functionality doesn't exist right now. Feel free to write it and open a pull request.